# how to make my android app which runs both on GSM & CDMA devices?

Tags: android

I've an android facebook application which runs good on my GSM.But when i run the same apk on CDMA devices.,its not getting loggin even.Do i need to sign up anything with that apk file in order to run it on CDMA devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to use the core networking functionality of a device, the radio the device uses is not important.

The fact that the app does not work on CDMA is some coincidence and the real issue is something else, likely related to an issue of the phone itself. What device is it, is this your own application, is their a stack trace or logs showing the connectivity failure?

Comment: s.Its my own facebook wall post application.Its WIFI connectivity has good signal strength.

Comment: Without more information all that can be done is guessing. I suggest debugging the application to see what is actually failing and formulate a new, more specific, question. All I can tell you is that radios do not make a difference when it comes to basic access of websites which is what it sounds like you are doing.